# Feynman lectures: historical updates?

Tags: history

I'm reading the Feynman Lectures and wonder if there is an overview over the historical Statements such as

> 12–6 Nuclear forces
>   [...] no one has ever calculated the force between two nuclei

Is this still true as of today? Is there a summary of today's state of affairs?